# нету графического интерфейса при запуске arch linux

Tags: archlinux

я поставил hyprland, но у меня была старая видеокарта nvidia gts250 и я не понимал мануал на вики и поэтому поставил по сомнительному репозиторию с гитхаба (hyprv4) по гайду какого то мужика на ютубе. при запуске выдает "the nvidia geforce gts250 gpu installed in this system is supported through the nvidia 340.xx legacy drivers. please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. the 535.54.03 nvidia driver will ignore this gpu. contining probe...". есть доступ к терминалу и больше не к чему. простите что без доп. информации, пишу с телефона, очень неудобно.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146874/discussion-on-question-by-vonper132------arc); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.